# Print the total population in from specific category within region column

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Population column with numbers and a Region column with locations. Im only using pandas. How would I go about finding the total population of a specific location (wellington) within the Region column?

[image]

Place = [data[‘Region’] == ‘Wellington’]

Place[data[‘Population’]]

an error came up

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [70], in <cell line: 4>()
1 #Q1.e
3 Place = [data['Region']=='Wellington']
----> 4 Place[data['Population']]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data_groups = data.groupby("Region")['Population'].sum()
```

Output:

```
data_groups

              Region
Northland     4750
Wellington    7580
WestCoast     1550
```

If you want to call some specific region, you can do:

```
data_groups.loc['WestCoast'] # 1550
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `sum`:

```
Place = data.loc[data['Region'] == 'Wellington', 'Population'].sum()
print (Place)
7190
```

Another idea is convert `Region` to index, select by [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) and then `sum`:

```
Place = data.set_index('Region')['Population'].loc['Wellington'].sum()
print (Place)
7190
```